# Accepting Shabbas before plag hamincha

Tags: shabbat, zemanim

The Aruch Hashulchan [263:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.263.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings the Terumas Hadeshen [#1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1835&pgnum=13) who speaks about a minhag of accepting shabas before plag and this was done by some communities.

> אבל בתפלה - פשיטא דהוי קבלה, וכן מצינו לקדמונים שהיו מתפללים ערבית כג' שעות קודם הלילה, וקבלו עליהם את השבת.
>
> But re *t'fila* - it is clearly acceptance [of *shabas*], "as we found among our predecessors who would daven *arvis* like 3 hours before night, and [thus] accepted *shabas*.

How would one explain this with [our halacha](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.233.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) of not accepting shabas before plag hamincha?

Comment: They didn't hold like us. How could someone explain it in terms of our halacha?

Comment: Like the gemara,I don't understand,can you explain why they would hold that is fine based of the gemara.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&st=&pgnum=187&hilite=

Comment: @sam There is no such explanation.

Comment: I know of at least one kehilla that does this.

Comment: http://www.tek-law.com/neshamah/early%20shabbat.htm

Comment: the explanation here https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/2011-2020/leff-maariv-early-erev-shabbat.pdf  would probably not be persuasive in most Orthodox communities

Comment: @rosends Actually I think it would be. As in I don't think an average Orthodox rabbi would be able to tell that wasn't written by an Orthodox rabbi. That Arukh haShulchan is often used to justify "Tarti-deSatri" prayers on Friday evenings even in Orthodox circles.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am in no position to argue with either the logic or substance of what he wrote -- I would anticipate people looking at the source and denying validity, or saying that it wouldn't fall within the scope of recognized authority on a site like this. I am probably wrong.

Comment: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=102941

Comment: You ask about accepting shabbat but your source is about the earliest time to daven maariv. Are you interested in justifying accepting shabbat before plag or davening maariv before plag? The former is much easier to justify since there is no source in the gemara that limits when you can accept shabbat.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the question the *T'rumas Hadeshen* was addressing.

> ברוב הקהילות נוהגין בימים ארוכים בימי הקיץ לקרות קריאת שמע של ערבית, ולהתפלל תפילת ערבית, ג' או ד' שעות לפני צאת הכוכבים. **אם יש שום ישוב או טעם למנהג זה**, כי גם הרבה תלמידי חכמים עם ההמון עם במנהג זה?‏

To paraphrase, "is there any justification for this widespread practice?" And his answer in short is "no". It opens with the words "...דאין בידינו כלל למצוא ישוב וטעם" - "we are totally unable to find a justification or reason..."

He does bring up the possibility(!) that the calculation of *p'lag hamincha*, which is subtracted from nightfall, could come out significantly earlier for some people, if they are calculating "hours" as twelfths of daylight rather than 60 minute periods, but dismisses this as helpful since no such long hours would be long enough to get *p'lag hamincha* 180 minutes before nightfall.

Short of justifying the extremely early *arvis* and *k'ri'as sh'ma*, he does hypothesize as to how it gained such adoption by respectable people. The leadership in places where night fell very late in the Summer (e.g. קרימ"ש) saw that people's inability to eat before *shabas* due to a safeguard emplaced in the *Ga'on* era was compelling them to forgo *t'fila*. So they saw fit to *allow* the early *t'fila* to go on.

He concludes by saying that if one is unable to prevail upon one's community to laten the schedule one need not abandon them, and would fulfill his obligations by joining them. He does not explain how/why. But it might be on the basis of such separation from the community constituting [undue arrogance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41250/3), which he alluded earlier.

> וכתב המרדכי ובהג"ה במיימון וראבי"ה כתב דדברי רבינו תם עיקר הם, והבא להחמיר על עצמו ולהמתין עד [צאת הכוכבים] כדברי שאר הגאונים, מחזי כיוהרא ונקרא הדיוט אם לא הורגל בשאר פרישות.‏

This would go as far as explaining his recommendation for one who is already embroiled, but not justifying the practice to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The Aruch Hashluchan that you quote ([263:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.263.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) actually answers the question.

> דאטו יש לנו שיעור לתוספת שנאמר דקודם לכן לא מהני.‏

*For where do we find a source for the length of Tosefes Shabbos, so that we can say "before that time it doesn't work"?*

IOW the burden of the proof would be on those that limit Tosefes Shabbos to Plag HaMincha to bring a source for that.

The full quote is:

> אף על פי שלהדלקה מהני תנאי לרוב הפוסקים, אפילו לדעת בה"ג שהדלקה הוי קבלת שבת כמו שנתבאר - מכל מקום לתפלה לא מהני תנאי. כגון **אם קדם היחיד והתפלל של שבת מבעוד יום**, אף על פי שהציבור לא התפללו עדיין - מכל מקום **חל עליו קבלת שבת, ומיד אסור במלאכה**, ואפילו אם אומר שאינו רוצה לקבל שבת. דכיון דהתפלל ערבית של שבת ובירך 'מקדש השבת' - בעל כורחו קביל עליו שבת, וזהו כמי שיאמר בלילה: 'איני רוצה לקבל שבת'.ויראה לי דבכהני גווני, **אפילו היה קודם פלג המנחה** - בעל כורחו קיבל עליו את השבת. ואף שנתבאר בסימן רס"א וכן בסימן רס"ז שאין לעשות תוספת קודם פלג המנחה ע"ש, וודאי **לכתחלה אין לעשות כן, אבל אם עשה כן מי ימחה בידו, *דאטו יש לנו שיעור לתוספת שנאמר דקודם לכן לא מהני***.וראיתי מי שכתב דזהו דווקא מפלג המנחה, (עיין מ"ב) ודברים תמוהים הם. אבל באמירת 'מזמור שיר ליום השבת' או 'לכה דודי' - בסתמא הוי קבלת שבת. אבל כשאמר בפירוש שאינו רוצה לקבל שבת - מועיל, דאין כאן תפלה וברכה לבטלה. וכן אם אמר זה קודם פלג המנחה - אפשר שאינו קבלה. (להמג"א בסימן קס"א סק"י בשם רי"ו) אבל בתפלה - פשיטא דהוי קבלה, וכן **מצינו לקדמונים שהיו מתפללים ערבית כג' שעות קודם הלילה, וקבלו עליהם את השבת**. (עיין תרומת הדשן סימן א' ושבות יעקב סימן חלק ב' סימן כ')‏