# Parameters of Yuhara - When should someone be concerned that he's overdoing it?

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits, stringency-chumrah, yuhara

There are many cases in halakha where one is discouraged from adopting a stringency because it appears to be an expression of 'religious haughtiness' (יוהרא).

When should someone be concerned about this? I assume that it matters how obvious the stringency would be to others, as well as how much, halakhically, one would gain by adhering to a higher standard. For example, what if everyone in your community does something in a way that is b'dieved permissible, but no posek believes it to be lechatchilah? What if it is to offset a personal issue (such as standing during the haftorah, which nobody does, in order to prevent oneself from falling asleep)?

Basically, does anyone know of a comprehensive discussion of the applicability of doing things that appear as yuhara?

Comment: R Schacter holds that wearing techeiles is not yuhara since it is in order to fulfill a mitzva doraisa,there is a Mishna Brura have to find it...

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2011/08/05/yuhara-laws-of-arrogance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sefer *Chayei Moshe*, by R' Moshe Mendel Shklarsh, in his section on *Klalei Psak V'Halacha*, discusses *yuhara*. He writes that it only applies to be stringent in public on something that, *min hadin* (according to the basic law) is permitted. (At the end of the discussion he mentions that some say it can even apply to private practices.)

There is a special concern with being stringent in the presence of one's rebbe who is not, as well as being stringent in a situation that implicitly denigrates the local rabbis.

I suspect that if the communal practice is actually only permissible *b'dieved*, i.e. after the fact, then it would not be *yuhara* to be stringent. On the contrary, it is basic halacha. However, people often use *b'di'eved* to simply mean that it is not the "best" or ideal, in which case it may be a problem. In general, such a determination needs to be made by a competent rabbi on a case by case basis.

As for offsetting a personal issue, in general this would not be an issue at all.

Comment: When I eat by my rav, he will tell me to go wash mayim acharonim. He doesn't.

Comment: Nu? I don't know why he doesn't wash himself, but if he tells you to do so it certainly isn't *yuhara*. (Which may be why he tells you to do so.)

Comment: Interestingly, I've found that many *Balei / at Teshuva* might be doing certain restriction sout of *yuhara*. In many cases, when I've asked them why they follow a "chumra" and I heard their reason, it was based upon an incorrect assumption o interpretation of the halachot involved. I don't believe then, that's called *yuhara*. I think it's called "foolishness".

Comment: I'm left wondering about this scenario: A person lives in a community that has adopted a stringency. He has previously set himself a rav who gives him psaks consistently and across the board, and has issued what the community thinks of as a kula in this one case. He follows it because he follows his rav. If he then decides to follow the stringency in public, even though it isn't a public display of arrogance, it is known to be an unnecessary and public following of a chumra. Is it yuhara?