# Why is wearing two pairs of tefillin simultaneosly not a violation of Lo Titgodedu (do not create factions)?

Tags: minhag, tefilin

[image]

There is a custom of some individuals to wear two pairs of tefillin at the same time. I understand based on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62610/7034) and similar answers that there is halachic basis for this practice. However, I believe it is self-evidently clear that this practice is rare and not normative. I would like to know why this practice does not violate the commandment of [Lo Titgodedu](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Lo_Titgodedu)

Comment: please note I cropped the photo to protect the identity of the person. Cropping it more made it difficult to understand what the picture was.

Comment: I'd have thought you'd first ask about Bal Tosif

Comment: Is this happening in public where everyone else is only wearing one pair? If not why would Lo Titgodedu apply?

Comment: Everyone agrres that Rabbeinu Tam tefillin are worn as a chumra....how is this any different from shmura matzah or glatt kosher?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would assume that only applies if one adds to the etzem mitzvah, not a chumrah/minhag

Comment: @DoubleAA my understanding is this practice is only performed by 'yichudei segulah' (not sure who to square this with maarat ayin or yuharah) at a minyan but even if the whole minyan did it it could still fall under lo titgodedu

Comment: @JoshK because of the appearance of fulfilling the mitzvah in a different way. See Rashi to Yevamot 13b

Comment: When I see people wearing two they usually cover one with a cloth, maybe for this reason

Comment: I live in Jerusalem and have seen at least 5 people wearing two pairs of tefillin simultaneously, and at minyanim where everyone else is wearing one pair.  I don't see this as being the same as shmura matza or glatt kosher, which are chumrot.  To me, this seems to be Baal Tosef, along the lines of having 8 parshiot in the Tefillin.  I can see a justification for wearing the Tefillin separately, accepting one pair as the Halacha, and the other pair as a chumra, or as adornments without a beracha.  What would we say to someone who puts up two mezzuot, one vertical and the other horizontal?

Comment: See Or LeTzion 2:3:8, Yabia Omer vol. 9 OC 108:21, Yalkut Yosef (Orach Chaim 34:2), Piskei Teshuvot 34:2. See Yaskil Avdi O.C. 8:22, Yabia Omer vol. 1 OC 3