# Standing during Torah reading in front of your Rabbi

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, standing-sitting, rebbe-talmid-muvhak, yuhara

Are you allowed to stand during Torah reading in front of your Rabbi who is sitting? (I think I heard that this might be a problem because it implies you are better than your Rabbi, or don't fully hold/agree with him.)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41250/parameters-of-yuhara-when-should-someone-be-concerned-that-hes-overdoing-it